# Adding a new contact in iOS 8 merges it with a homonymous old contact

Tags: ios, contacts

I have in my iPhone iOS 8 and old contact called Salvador. This old contact has his mobile, and some notes, and that is fine.

Today I select a phone number from my call history and select the add a new contact option. I enter the name contact as Salvador and add a note to this new contact.

The problem is when I recall from my contact app the Salvador name, it only appears once (I'm supposed to have an Old Salvador and the new Salvador as a contact) when I select the Salvador contact the info inside is a combination of the phone and notes of the old Salvador and the phone and notes of the new Salvador.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one contact with the same name in your iPhone so it sounds like your iPhone is merging them together. Try adding a last name/nick name to have them as two separate contacts.